# Do we reside in any particular dimension(s)?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

In other words does it make sense to say that we live or exist in dimension *x*? Or do dimensions not apply to <s>reality</s> the universe its self?

Comment: No, it does not make sense (we do not live in *a* dimension, but we live in *a space spanned by x amount of directions*). But your second question does not depend on your first question, so you should not write "Or".

Answer (score 6):

In science fiction it's not uncommon to see phrases like "travel into the fourth dimension" as if the "fourth dimension" was something you could leave our universe and travel into. However this is not what the word *dimension* means in physics. The dimension of a spacetime is simply the number of co-ordinates needed to locate a point within it. For example to locate a point in our spacetime you just give its position and time $(t, x, y, z)$ so our spacetime is four dimensional (three space dimensions and one time).

So it doesn't make any sense to say we live in *dimension x*, but it does make sense to say we live in a *4 dimensional spacetime*.

Comment: well, if string theory becomes the theory of everything, as it promises, we are living in at least  ten dimensions, the every day four and the atleast six curled up ones.

Comment: There are those of us who (with absolutely **no** reliable evidence :-) suspect that the dimensionality of spacetime is an emergent property anyway.